# How to run a .mexw64 file on Mac?

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries, cross-platform, reverse-engineering, mex

I've downloaded a file (`ListFunc.mexw64`) containing some functions I'd like to use in my algorithm. I am using **Mac OS** but, it seems incompatible with OS as well as the MATLAB software itself.

Is there a way to get it to work or to see the content of the file?

Answer (score 4):

A `mexw64` file is compiled for Win64 systems, the equivalent extension for macOS is [`mexmaci64`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html#btw3s7f-4) - this file simply **wasn't meant** to be used on a macOS.

You should try to contact the authors of the file and ask them to recompile it for Mac, or ask for the source code and compile it yourself, according to [these instructions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html).